# How can I get Aptana to work with Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, aptana

Is there a way for me to get Google Chrome to launch in Aptana?

I tried adding it under **Web Browsers** but when launching the webpage, from Aptana, it launches it in Firefox instead.

Selecting **Default system browser** doesn't work either.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

How I would do it is where the green > button is, at the top (next to debug), go into run configuration and add a new entry for google chrome.

The path for chromes exe is at (Win7)

`C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe`

WinXP

`C:\Documents and Settings\<username>\Local Settings\Application\chrome.exe`

Then you can run that straight from the drop down menu. This is the way I do it, however it may not be applicable for your situation.

Comment: You're right, not really applicable to my situation but close enough :)

Comment: I've never used the Web Browsers function, whats the difference?

Comment: I'm a bit new to Aptana but I guess the only difference is hitting the green > button will launch the site in the Web Browser you have selected under Web Browers. Your answer involved 2 clicks to launch the site. But then again i'm a bit picky and only wanted to do it in 1 click :P

Comment: You could set it as the default entry, so when you click the green button (not the dropdown), so it opens up straight away :)

Comment: Tried that. Doesn't work and hence the question. For some strange reason it launches Firefox instead of Chrome when done that way.

Comment: Have been trying a few different ways to get Aptana to run in Chrome but this solution finally did it. Thanks rickyduck.

Comment: On Windows 8 64-bit, the path to chrome is: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe". Remove the double-quotes when entering this path into Aptana 3.3.2's Browser Executable field in the "Run Configurations" dialog box - and everything will be sweet as.

Comment: I tried the path given by RickyDuck above, but I get this message: Error Code 10061: Connection refused
Background: The server you are attempting to access has refused the connection with the gateway. This usually results from trying to connect to a service that is inactive on the server.

I don't have problems with Firefox...in my dropdown menu from the green run outton in Aptana, I notice that Firefox is given as 'Firefox - Internal Server', while Chrome is just 'Chrome'...did I configure something wrong?

Comment: The path for Google Chrome on Windows 7 seems to have changed in version 36. Mine appears in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Application\chrome.exe`. Just thought I'd put that out there for others who are also wondering where it is located - and so that this answer is up-to-date.

Answer (score 2):

I added Chrome to the Run Configurations ...
I deleted Firefox from the General > Web Browser settings.
I restarted Aptana Studio 3 and now, when I click on the green arrow run button, Chrome is the browser.

Say hello to F12 and debugging HTML and JavaScript with ease.

Answer (score 1):

I have Windows 7 and followed the advice listed above for the 'green button'.  For Chrome, my file path was "C:\Users\user name\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe".  It was very simple and worked beautifully.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

rickyduck's answer applies but the path to Chrome may have changed in newer versions to :

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe`

That's the path I had to use.

Answer (score 0):

rickyduck's answer is exactly what I have been looking for! Thanks Ricky!

To get the exact path to chrome on your machine, just go to your start menu, type in chrome and when it comes up, right click on it and select the Shortcut tab to copy the target path and paste right into Aptana.

Comment: This is not an anwser. You should have written this as a comment to the answer you're talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to directly launch chrome upon pressing green button is to delete other browsers from run -> run configuration -> web browser . . . and leave chrome alone . . if you want other browsers you can add later on . .

Answer (score 0):

You can add as many browsers as you want. Click on Run -> Run Configurations then right-click on Web Browser in the left nav pane, then select New. Use the Browse button to get the application path then at the top of the dialog, type in a descriptive name. Click Apply and Close. You now have more than one browser to choose from for testing.

Answer (score 0):

I added Chrome to run configurations, and deleted Firefox and IE, also changed likewise under General Web Browsers.  The Chrome tab doesn't show up on Green dropdown.  If I exit program and restart, the Firefox and IE are back again, but still now Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Click the tiny **black arrow** thats looks at the bottom and is located at the top, next to the *green Run button*:

[image]

Choose **Run Configurations** and then you should see a **Browser executable** field, under the *Web Browser* tab:

[image]

where you want to click **Browse**, navigate to the *Google Chrome executable* (at my Max OS X at El capitan: Applications -> Google Chrome) and *double click* on it.

Then, click **Apply** (in the Run Configurations window). Then **Run**.

That's it! :)

---

Tested with Aptana Studio 3, [installed like this on Mac](http://tutorialforlinux.com/2014/01/31/how-to-install-aptana-studio-3-on-mac-os-x-10-9-mavericks-easy-guide/).